# Is "lay" in this sentence in the correct tense?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

I'm making a description for an app, this strikes me as a bit awkward for some reason:

> "I wanted to create an app that lay somewhere between an ecosystem and a musical instrument."

Is the word *lay* in the correct tense?

Comment: @Miles: In the future, if your question is closed, you can edit the existing question. If enough high-rep users think that your question is in the guidelines, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. "Lay" is the simple past tense form of the intransitive verb "lie". The sentence you've quoted is grammatically correct.

What confuses people is that "lay" is *also* a transitive verb in the present tense--chickens lay eggs. The past tense of that verb is "laid".

Answer (score 0):

While your sentence is correct, you might find using *fit* sounds closer to what you're meaning to say.

> I wanted to create an app that fit somewhere between an ecosystem and a musical instrument

Answer (score 0):

You might make it sound less odd by using "fell" or by omitting "that lay" entirely.